# accessory action segue (UITableViewController)

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, uitableview

I'm trying to make segue via IB, that switching views when pressed cell accessory in tableView.

Images from my IB:

1.I'm dragging from cell of tableviewcontroller to another view and selecting Accessory Action -> push

[image: IB screenshot]

and when i'm running my project i get error:

> [ setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key accessoryActionSegueTemplate

I think that this might be something wrong with reuseIdentifier of cell.

My `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method:

```
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"champion cell";
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

NSString *cellIconName = ((championList *)[self.champions objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]).championImage;
UIImage *cellIcon = [UIImage imageNamed:cellIconName];
[[cell imageView] setImage:cellIcon];

cell.imageView.frame = CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, 70.0f, 70.0f);

cell.imageView.layer.cornerRadius = 7;
[cell.imageView.layer setMasksToBounds:YES];

cell.textLabel.text = ((championList *) [self.champions objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]).championName;
cell.detailTextLabel.text = ((championList *) [self.champions objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]).championId;

return cell;
```

---

I can use performSegueWithIdentifier: method as solution of this problem, but i want to figure out why i having problem with accessory action in IB.

Comment: Strange bug! Xcode help found nothing for the search key "accessoryActionSegueTemplate" and google also found nothing...

Comment: I think that is's some kind of apple bug. Hope they fix it soon..

Comment: What version of iOS are you using? My app was originally written for iOS 6 but a last minute decision change required me to back port it to iOS 5. After doing this I started to encounter this error. This isn't necessarily the answer you're looking for but this issue appears to be limited to iOS 5 as the same code works fine on iOS 6.

Comment: yep, my app is also originally written for iOS 6 and then ported to iOS 5

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I had this problem when I had ctrl-dragged a segue from the detail accessory button of the prototype cell to the next view controller. So instead I did the drag from the table view controller itself, and added a bit of code to it.

**Objective-C:**

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView accessoryButtonTappedForRowWithIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier: @"EditUser" sender: [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath: indexPath]];
}
```

**Swift 3.0:**

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, accessoryButtonTappedForRowWith indexPath: IndexPath) {
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "EditUser", sender: tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath))
}
```

This works for iOS 5.0 - 10.x

Comment: This is the answer. Accessory action seques are iOS 6.0+ only, so if you have one of these in your  StoryBoard then it will bomb out with that `accessoryActionSegueTemplate` error on any previous iOS

Comment: Great post, I used your method and I added an if statement before attempting to seque. ie.`if (indexPath.section == 0 && indexPath.row == 0)` since I have multiple accessory buttons in my tableview

Comment: I have also run into this error (only for iOS 5). I have a tableView in a ViewController and I'm unable to "drag from the tableViewController itself" to link the seque. How did you manage to do that? Regards

Comment: I have the same problem with Filip! Any ideas?

Comment: do the drag from the grey area where it says "Table View", rather than from some cell.

Comment: You can add the same code to -(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didDeselectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath, if accessoryButtonTappedForRowWithIndexPath doesn't work for you

Answer (score 2):

I'm getting this error when I run my application on iOS 5 on an iPod Touch and not on iOS 6 on an iPhone 5.

The docs say that accessory action was deprecated in iOS 3.0. The bug seems to be that it's being shown and allowed in iOS 6.

Can you confirm what version of iOS you're testing against?

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewCell_Class/DeprecationAppendix/AppendixADeprecatedAPI.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UITableViewCell/accessoryAction

Answer (score 1):

I just ran into the same problem. Works fine on iOS 6, crashes on 5.1.

The way I solved it is by using a standard `UITableViewCell` and creating the accessory button out of a `UIButton`, on which I put a segue.

Comment: YES YES YES!! If I could I would run all the way to Russia (Guess based on your name ^^) and give you a hug and a dinner! Thanks, been trying to fix this problem for hours!

Answer (score 1):

On iOS 5.x, this error also occurs when you create a popover style segue in a storyboard, and (in my case) anchor it to a UITableViewCell.

In this case, the error message is a completely misleading red herring.

I'm assuming that iOS 5.x doesn't support anchored popover segues.

Comment: I'm wondering if that's my problem.  Did you get anywhere with this?

Answer (score -2):

Drag a navigationController from object library to your storyboard file and try to do this, it should work.Your next View should have the navigation controller.

Comment: thanks for response! But adding navigation controller to next view didn't help