# Exception related to accessoryActionSegueTemplate

Tags: ios, ios5

I got exception on on `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:`

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"pointcell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];// Here is exception 
    if( cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    ...

    return cell;
}
```

Exception:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<UITableViewCell 0xca51470> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key accessoryActionSegueTemplate.'
```

I did set identifier to Custom type cell in Storyboard. I have set Accessory Action segue in Storyboard. I think it's related to that particular type but I don't understand what should I do prevent crash.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems a bit too late, but I've just faced the same problem and found a solution.

When you Control+Dragging a segue from UITableViewCell in Interface Builder it offers you to create a segue for cell or accessory view. If you create it for accessory view and run your app under iOS 5 you are in trouble since accessory segues were not supported in that version.

You can drag a segue from ViewController instead and include this code ([taken from here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13000184/629961)):

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView accessoryButtonTappedForRowWithIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"SegueID" 
                              sender:[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath]];
}
```