# Accessory action vs selection segue

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, xcode

Anyone know the difference between an accessory action and a selection segue? I linked a cell to a tableviewcontroller. Also, by linking an item button to the table view controller i get an action segue option and not accessory action! Im confused

Comment: I'm not sure I get what you mean. Did you want to compare the ways of navigating from a view controller to another using either `prepareForSegue` or button's `touchUpInside` event?

Comment: have a look at this [ans](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12617219/accessory-action-segue-uitableviewcontroller). Hope it helps

Answer (score 16, accepted):

First of all I think it's good to know what an **accessory** is. The `accessory` property is an instance property of the `UITableViewCell` (therefore you cannot define an accessory action for an `UIButton`). It is a view which appears on the right side of the cell in the table view's normal state. The default accessory style is `none`, meaning there is no additional view on the right side of the `UITableViewCell`.

An accessory action is a segue which gets triggered when you touch the accessory view on the right side of the cell. Apple provides a set of predefined types (link provided below) of accessories. In order to support accessory actions an accessory must track touches. There are currently two predefined accessories which does that, the `detailDisclosureButton` and `detailButton`.

A simple example demonstrating the usage of action accessories:

[image]

If you touch the accessory view (the `'i'` icon, the `'Detail'` accessory type) you get to the meta data view. If you touch any other part of the cell you get to the content view.

There are two different ways to set the accessory type. One is through the attribute inspector of an instance of `UITableViewCell` under the section `'Accessory'`. The other way is via code, using this method:

```
var accessoryType: UITableViewCellAccessoryType { get set }
```

For more information, check the Apple Documentation overview for accessory types:
**https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableviewcellaccessorytype**.